# comparing sub-bitsets in C++

Tags: c++, bitset

I have two bitsets `std::bitset<200> A` and `std::bitset<200> B` and I would like to compare the bits `A[10-60]` and `B[50-100]`. I am extracting the 50 bits in both bitsets into another two bitsets and then comparing them like following. Is there any better approach?

```
std::bitset<200> A, B;
// A and B are already set
std::bitset<50> x, y;
for(int i=10; i<=60; i++)
  if(A.test(i)) x.set(i);
for(int i=50; i<=100; i++)
  if(B.test(i)) y.set(i);

if( x == y) ....
```

Comment: It looks like your loops have an off-by-one error, which would throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about looping both bitsets, A and B, together?

```
bool same = true;
for (size_t ai = 10, bi = 50; ai != 60; ++ai, ++bi) {
  if (A.test(ai) != B.test(bi) {
    same = false;
    break;
  }
}
// same denotes if the sections of A and B are equal.
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. I was wondering if some faster bitwise operation can be done without comparing each and every bit.